# Перемещение маркеров по карте в Yandex.Mapkit API

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

Можно ли переместить маркер с одного места на другое на карте в приложении под Android, и если можно, то как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Для этого нужно будет изменить координаты метки через [PlacemarkMapObject.setGeometry()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/map/PlacemarkMapObject.html#_6)

Если речь о перемещении метки вручную (драгом) для этого она должна иметь соответствующую опцию: [isDraggable](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/map/MapObject.html#_10) = true

Наглядно вариант перетаскивания можно посмотреть в [примере](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode) родственной МапКиту JS API Яндекса.

Comment: Имеется ввиду, программно изменить положение метки? А можно реализовать как-то перемещение метки, при тапе по ней и перетаскивании пользователем?

Comment: Дополнил ответ про драг.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь всё понятно!